# How to configure vim to not put comments at the beginning of lines while editing python files

Tags: python, vim

When I add a # in insert mode on an empty line in Vim while editing python files, vim moves the # to the beginning of the line, but I would like the # to be inserted at the tab level where I entered it.

For example, when writing this in vim

```
for i in range(10):
    #
```

the # does not stay there where I entered it.

It is moved like so, by vim.

```
for i in range(10):
#
```

Does anyone know of a configuration item in vim that would change this?

If it helps, I am using Ubuntu 8.10.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191201/indenting-comments-to-match-code-in-vim

Comment: simply use the command `:set cinkeys-=0# indentkeys-=0#` to remove `0#` from the both settings (at most times, changing `cinkeys` is enough)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found an answer here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restoring_indent_after_typing_hash

It seems that the vim smartindent option is the cause of the problem.
The referenced page above describes work-a-rounds but after reading the help in smartindent in vim itself (:help smartindent), I decided to try cindent instead of smartindent.

I replaced

```
set smartindent
```

with

```
set cindent
```

in my .vimrc file

and so far it is working perfectly.

This changed also fixed the behavior of '<<' and '>>' for indenting visual blocks that include python comments.

There are more configuration options for and information on indentation in the vim help for smartindent and cindent (:help smartindent and :help cindent).

Comment: Ah, I have "filetype plugin indent on" in my .vimrc, perhaps that's responsible for it working correctly for me.  http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html

Comment: is there any recommended/common configuration settings for `cindent`?

Comment: This has annoyed me forever, and I finally took the 5 minutes to fix it (sounds like most vim problems, right?). Thanks for the breadcrumbs!

Answer (score 22):

@PolyThinker Though I see that response a lot to this question, in my opinion it's not a good solution. The editor still thinks it should be indented all the way to left - check this by pushing == on a line that starts with a hash, or pushing = while a block of code with comments in it is highlighted to reindent.

I would strongly recommend `filetype indent on`, and remove the `set smartindent` and `set autoindent` (or `set cindent`) lines from your vimrc. Someone else (appparently David Bustos) was kind enough to write a full indentation parser for us; it's located at $VIMDIRECTORY/indent/python.vim.

(Paul's `cindent` solution probably works for python, but `filetype indent on` is much more generally useful.)

Comment: Thanks - this helped me out.  I had one hitch, and that's I was trying "filetype indent on" within gvim (MacVim) and saw no behavior change.  Once I started testing it by adding it to .vimrc, then restarting, I saw behavior change.

Comment: Same problem, tried accepted solutions (and permutations), placed 'filetye indent on' at end of .vimrc, and now #comment'ing python does not de/outdent. But now the thing autoindents for me. Sigh.

Comment: Turn off smartindent doesn't work for me (on both ubuntu vim and osx mac-vim).   Adding "filetype indent on" to my $HOME/.vimrc and restarting [g]vim solve my problem (on both python and bash script editing).

Answer (score 12):

I have the following lines in my .vimrc, seems to be installed by default with my Ubuntu 8.10

```
set smartindent
inoremap # X^H#
set autoindent
```

And I don't observe the problem. Maybe you can try this. (Note that ^H should be entered by Ctrl-V Ctrl-H)

Comment: This fix is outlined in the docs (`:help smartindent`).  I think `set autoindent` is redundant; `smartindent` includes it

Answer (score 4):

My solution to the unindenting of #:

If you use cindent, recognize that it is designed for C and C++ coding.  Here, a # means you are creating a #DEFINE or #MACRO(), so the behavior is correct.  But for other languages where # is a comment, it is irritating.

The following worked for me:

```
" cindent       enable specific indenting for C code
" set cin       nocin
set cin

" cinkeys       The default cinkeys causes leading # to unindent to column 0.
"               To prevent this, remove the 0# from the definition.
" set cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e - default
set cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,!^F,o,O,e
```

Comment: For easy typing on the keyboard, the last command can be shortened to: `set cink-=0#` (i.e.: "remove (`-=`) the `0#` entry from the list of entries in the `cink[eys]` variable")

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by the 'smartindent' feature. If you have `:set smartindent` in your .vimrc you need to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other answers were useful, but none were enough to prevent Vim from reindenting a line when '#' is the first character. PolyThinker's answer didn't work for me, but it gave a clue that '#' could be remapped to "insert a character, then #, then delete the extra character and put the cursor where it should be". This is the mapping that does that:

```
inoremap # X#<left><backspace><right>
```

This is needed because vim's syntax packages seem to treat '#' as a special character, no matter how the options are set. I want a line started with '#' to be the same as a line begun with any other character. The most reliable solution I've found is the above mapping, which actually does change the line's first character.

Note: I've found this mapping causes problems after running `I#<esc>` then pressing "." to redo the previous insertion. I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

My Vim configuration doesn't do that.  You might try the python.vim script available from this link:  http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work in my case, the problem persists while using it.  
I used version 2.6.3 because I have not yet upgraded to python 3.0.

Perhaps the problem is in the /usr/share/vim/vim71/indent/python.vim file installed from the Ubuntu vim-runtime package?

Answer (score 0):

I removed `set smartindent` from `~/.vimrc` but it still didn't disable smartindent. When I opened a .py file and ran `:set smartindent?` it displayed `smartindent`.

Turns out that further down in the `~/.vimrc` was this line:

```
autocmd BufRead *.py set smartindent cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Once I deleted "smartindent" from that line, then smartindent was finally disabled and my comments were indented properly again.