# How not to remove indentation by inserting `#`?

Tags: vim, indentation, vi, auto-indent

When using the `autoindent` configuration from VIM, it will automatically indent your cursor to a meaningful position after creating a new line. But when the first character you enter is a hash character (`#`) then the indentation will be removed and the `#` will be inserted as the first character of the line.

**Why does this happen? How to configure VIM to not do that?**

Example (`_` as the empty cursor position):

```
def python_function():
    _
```

after clicking the`#` on the keyboard this happens:

```
def python_function():
#_
```

but what *should* have happened is this:

```
def python_function():
    #_
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191201/indenting-comments-to-match-code-in-vim and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385327/what-setting-in-vim-counteracts-smartindents-refusal-to-indent-comments-in-sh

Comment: You are right, I just didn't really know how to search that term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have `smartindent` or `cindent` instead of (or as well as) `autoindent`; these indent styles are designed for C-syntax languages.  It's a good idea when editing Python to use `:filetype plugin indent on` as this will load appropriate indent settings for Python.

Answer (score 4):

`:help smartindent`

Use the mapping `:inoremap # X^H#` (^h is entered via CTRL-V CTRL-H)

Comment: The help section on smartindent gives a brief explanation.  vim has a strong legacy as an editor for C source code, and typically lines beginning with '#' are not indented.

Comment: @erikb85, The answer to your question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156448/autoindent-smartindent-and-indentexpr

Answer (score 0):

For me it was also the case that the indentation was not properly working when I have forgotten to disable paste mode with :set nopaste, when initially turning it on for copy pasting.