# Autoindent : smartindent and indentexpr

Tags: vim, auto-indent

When I'm editing a Python file, for example:

```py
def my_func():
    print('Something')
    <-- CURSOR IS HERE
```

and I want to add a comment by typing a `#`, the line is automatically reindenting to the very beginning of the line:

```py
def my_func():
    print('Something')
#<-- CURSOR IS HERE
```

I found that it's an effect of the `smartindent` option, so to fix it, I just have to run `:set nosi` (or disable it in my .vimrc).

But in Vim's help, in `:h 'smartindent'`, you can read this:

> When 'cindent' is on or 'indentexpr' is set, setting 'si' has no effect.

But my `indentexpr` option is set to the following:

```
:set indentexpr?
indentexpr=GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)
```

I certainly should avoid using `smartindent` option at all, since it looks to be an old feature, and is designed to work with C-style languages only;

But I wonder why `smartindent` does have some effect when I'm editing python files, considering what is written in the help?

Comment: When I have `smartindent` off and `indentexpr=GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)`, it behaves normally and doesn't do what you described. Probably some plugin is overriding or has conflicting settings.

Comment: @Atri : I've asked about when `smartindent` is *on*. I just wrote that `:set nosi` solved the issue, but my question is about the content of Vim's help, which doesn't fit the real behaviour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, It does behaved the same way you explained.

In my case `:echo GetPythonIndent(v:lnum)` returns `-1`

`:h  indentexpr` has following text explaining the behaviour.

```
 The expression must return the number of spaces worth of indent. It
 can return "-1" to keep the current indent (this means 'autoindent' is
 used for the indent).
```

As we set `si`, it takes over `ai`.

Now `:h si` suggest a work around:

```
:inoremap # X^H#
```

where ^H is entered as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

I am sure you will have a better solution than the work around provided

Comment: You pointed it out: when `GetPythonIndent` returns `-1`, the `si` option is used. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that the answer was useful to you